# PyLint highlighting globally declared variables as undefined

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I recently switched from PyCharm to VS Code, and get a lot of error messages from PyLint for globally declared variables(parameters read out of a json file). The same file doesnt show any errors in PyCharm, and the code runs without problems. Whats PyLints problem here?

Answer (score 0):

PyLint mainly checks for code style. They are not necessarily errors, instead think of them as suggestions. I'm guessing you just didn't have PyLint added to your PyCharm so you haven't encountered these before.

Comment: Is there any way to configure PyLint then? And what does PyLint suggest for global variables then?

Comment: [Here's an overview for python linting settings in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting). As for the second question,I don't know the specifics of your project or what pylint is warning you about so I can't tell you what it would suggest for your global variables. If you look up the message/code it gives you then you should be able to find more information.